# Scikit-image Regionprops Orientation value

Tags: python, image-processing, orientation, scikit-image

My question is pretty simple, but I haven't been able to find an answer. One can measure objects in an image using scikit-image's regionprops method. One of the properties there is available is orientation of the object. My question is, how can be the value in range from -pi/2 to pi/2 (https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops) if in the source code which is linked in the documentation, it appears that the values should be in range from -pi/4 to pi/4.

```
def orientation(self):
    a, b, b, c = self.inertia_tensor.flat
    if a - c == 0:
        if b < 0:
            return -PI / 4.
        else:
            return PI / 4.
    else:
        return 0.5 * atan2(-2 * b, c - a)
```

I will be glad for clarifying.

Comment: `atan2` returns a value in the range [-pi, pi].

Comment: Well, I supposed I didn't think about that, but I might have additional question, because I am not sure where this formula came from. To be specific, wherever I was looking and reading about this, I saw only atan(), not atan2(). That's why I was also asking about the -pi/4 to pi/4 range since atan() returns values from -pi/2 to pi/2

Comment: I'm doubting this code. This should compute the angle of one of the eigenvectors of the inertia tensor. If you compute the eigenvectors according to [these equations](http://people.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math21b2004/exhibits/2dmatrices/index.html) then you'd have at least one square root in there, which I don't see in this code. I also don't understand why they're using half the angle. This might be some clever optimization, I'd need to look into this.

Comment: Okey, so I found out what I was missing. The thing was, that I misunderstood the atan2 function, which is basically arctan but returns the values in radians. The problem I was looking at can be found for example here: http://raphael.candelier.fr/?blog=Image%20Moments the equation for the angle. It confused me, since I never saw the atan2() function before. Anyway, Thank you for the help.